# Tkinter: calling a function only once while updating every 1 millisecond on a multiple of a certain number

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making a clicker game and there is this upgrade where if generator 1 (worst generator) is on a multiple of 5, it increases the total amount the player gets per second by 0.5. For example, if I have 5,10,15... of generator 1 and I bought the upgrade, I will get an extra 0.5/1.0/1.5... per second.

Like assume it is 1.5/sec with 5 generator 1 (0.1/sec per generator), after buying the upgrade, it turns to 2.0/sec. After buying 5 more generator 1 (10 generator 1), it should be 3.0/sec instead of 3.5/sec.

```py
def updater2():
    upgrade_2_checker()
    root.after(1, updater2) # updates/checks every 1 millisecond

def upgrade_2_checker(): # for every multiple of 5, call the upgrade_2_adder function ONCE even if it is stuck on the multiple of 5
    global generator_1_amount
    while generator_1_amount % 5 == 0: # right now it will keep calling the function every millisecond if generator_1_amount is on a multiple of 5
        upgrade_2_adder()
    else:
        pass

def upgrade_2_adder(): # for every multiple of 5, this function gets called ONCE even if it is stuck on the multiple of 5
    global total_auto
    global generator_1_amount
    total_auto = total_auto + (int(generator_1_amount / 5) * 0.5)
```

This is the code right now for the upgrade, there is a comment which indicates the problem but I'm gonna say it here as well. Right now it will keep on calling the upgrade_2_adder function every 1 millisecond if the generator_1_amount is on a multiple of 5. I know something is missing to make it only call once if generator_1_amount is on a multiple of 5 and I couldn't think of anyway to not call the function more than 1 time if the amount is stuck on a multiple of 5, like stuck on 5.

Answer (score 2):

To ensure that the `upgrade_2_adder` function is called only once when `generator_1_amount` is on a multiple of 5, you can introduce a variable to keep track of whether the upgrade has already been applied.

```
def updater2():
    upgrade_2_checker()
    root.after(1, updater2)  # updates/checks every 1 millisecond

def upgrade_2_checker():
    global generator_1_amount
    if generator_1_amount % 5 == 0:  # Check if generator_1_amount is a multiple of 5
        upgrade_2_adder()

def upgrade_2_adder():
    global total_auto
    global generator_1_amount
    global upgrade_2_applied

    if not upgrade_2_applied:  # Check if the upgrade has already been applied
        total_auto += (generator_1_amount // 5) * 0.5
        upgrade_2_applied = True  # Set the upgrade flag to indicate it has been applied
```

Comment: that is not really what i want since if i have 5 generator 1, it still only adds 0.5 extra to total_auto, but after i got 10 generator 1, it adds extra 1.0 instead of another 0.5. i guess i didnt frame the question well enough, though it is good enough to help me modify it

Comment: Add a boolean, for example 'callGeneratorNextTime' and set it to false when the if statement is true and the function is upgrade_2_adder is called. When the if-statement is false, set the boolean to true. Before function call, check for the boolean.